# Ubuntu 22.10 display issue on laptop

Tags: boot

I have loaded Ubuntu 22.10 on a laptop.  While the install is progressing all looks well.  Afterwards when I boot up the screen does not display correctly.  The resolution is poor, images are distorted, and everything is showing in triplicate spaced out along the screen.  Does not run.

Using the same USB drive I have loaded Ubuntu 22.10 onto another laptop.  It works well, except for the mouse pad doesn't work.  I have to use a usb trackball instead.

Answer (score 0):

if possible try:
1)make sure you are connected to the internet.
2)applications==>Software & Updates==> additional drivers and then click on the driver then Apply changes